# embedded google map in my site, I disabled the UI, but I can still pan and zoom the map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, coffeescript

I used [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) to embed a google map in my website, I initialise the map with this coffeescript:

```
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google')
    handler.buildMap {
      provider: {
        disableDefaultUI: true
      }
      internal: id: 'map'}, ->
      handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

My intention is to prevent the users from exploring (pan, zoom, etc) the map. I'm trying to do so by using the `disableDefaultUI: true`

With this control the arrows and other controls actually disappear, but I can still explore my map with the touchpad (I tested it on Chrome on osx)

How can I get my map to be more *static*? thanks.

Comment: In the options when setting up the map, set draggable to false.

Comment: Thanks, apparently that's not sufficient, I need also `scrollwheel` to false, and I'm figuring what else. this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20646771/1089494

Comment: I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20646771/1089494 which addresses the issue. 

Thanks